# Cannot connect to IBOutlet in a new custom class Xcode 11

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, iboutlet

I am working on an iOS project in Xcode 11 to create an app that converts Farenheit to Celsius. I deleted the default ViewController.swift file and created a custom class with a more descriptive name called ConversionViewController.swift. This file was then saved to the current project. The file contains these lines of code:

```
class ConversionViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var celsiusLabel: UILabel!

    @IBAction func fahrenheitFieldEditingChanged(_ textField: UITextField) {
        celsiusLabel.text = textField.text
    }
}
```

In Main.storyboard I selected the `View Controller` in the document outline then opened the identity inspector. In the `Custom Class` section of the identity inspector I changed the class to `ConversionViewController` and below the module field I checked `Inherit module from target`. Next, I want to create an outlet to the Celsius text label and create an action for the text field to call when the text changes. So, I open Main.storyboard and try to control-drag from the `Conversion View Controller` in the document outline to the Celsius label and connect it to the `celsiusLabel` in ConversionViewController.swift.

The problem is that Xcode won't let me. When I control-drag from the `Conversion View Controller` to the Celsius label nothing happens. I don't get a pop-up box that gives me the option to select the outlet `celsiusLabel`.

I've tried going to Product --> Clean Build Folder but that didn't fix the problem. Is there a step missing? I am using the iOS Programming: Big Nerd Ranch Guide 6th edition, which I know isn't written for Xcode 11.

Comment: If I understand correctly you are control dragging from your swift file to the storyboard. In this case you don't actually need to control drag, but just drag from the empty circle on the left of your celsiusLabel outlet to the actual UILabel in your storyboard. Alternatively you can try control dragging from your storyboard to the swift file and then you will get the popup you mentioned.

Comment: I may be late but I'm pretty sure the problem was related to the fact that you've deleted the default ViewController class. By deleting it you have also deleted the connection between the controller and the main storyboard. To connect it back to the new controller class you have to click on the storyboard, go inside the Id inspector and change the class attribute to your custom ViewController class.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by refactoring the name of the ViewController instead of just renaming it.

Control-click the symbol and choose Refactor > Rename.

Answer (score 0):

> When I control-drag from the Conversion View Controller to the Celsius label nothing happens. I don't get a pop-up box that gives me the option to select the outlet celsiusLabel.

Yes, I often see that problem. Usually I can solve it by dragging a different way. For example, select the label, switch on the right to the Connections inspector, and drag from the circle next to New Referencing Outlet onto the view controller in the outline. Now does it let you make the connection?

Answer (score 0):

In your StoryBoard select the ViewController by clicking on top where the name is displayed after that select the connections inspector (last option). You will see your celsius label there under outlets. Drag from the label's empty circle there to the label in the ViewController's View and connect.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem:- 
It will be resolved by two ways:-

1) After changing the name of the .swift file just clean the build. If it not lets you create outlet then just quit the xcode and run it again then it will allow you to add outlet to the class.

2). In the connections Inspector select the circle coming under Referencing Outlets and drag that to the viewController to create outlet of the control.

Answer (score 0):

This typically happens to me when I move or rename a file. The fix in those circumstances is to remove the file from the 'compile sources' list, then re-add. Then build (no need for clean build).